# ubuntu server crash after build.sh run

Tags: kernel, memory-usage

I have a build server with Ubuntu. And in my source code there is typical `build.sh` to invoke the make file in order to compile the source code. But suddenly the server crashed and I found the below log in `syslog`:

```
Aug  4 13:47:28 VDBS1130 kernel: [2689989.302589] build.sh invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=1, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Aug  4 13:47:28 VDBS1130 kernel: [2689989.302593] build.sh cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Aug  4 13:47:28 VDBS1130 kernel: [2689989.302596] Pid: 8978, comm: build.sh Not tainted 3.2.0-60-generic-pae #91-Ubuntu
Aug  4 13:47:28 VDBS1130 kernel: [2689989.302598] Call Trace:
```

Can anyone tell me what does it mean? Can my local `build.sh` crash the kernel?

Comment: Post the rest of the syslog as well. It will contain more information and memory stats.

Answer (score 0):

The [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) is activated when the system has a severe shortage of memory:

> It is the job of the linux 'oom killer' to sacrifice one or more processes in order to free up memory for the system when all else fails. It will also kill any process sharing the same `mm_struct` as the selected process, for obvious reasons. Any particular process leader may be immunized against the oom killer if the value of its `/proc/<pid>/oomadj` is set to the constant `OOM_DISABLE` (currently defined as -17).

Things to check:

- Is something in your build script taking up a lot of memory?
- Are there memory leaks in some tool you are using?

Have a look at [this LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/).